# How to write this query and not have all columns in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query

```
SELECT child.* 
FROM [nested-set] AS parent
JOIN (
  SELECT [lft] AS parentLft, [rgt] AS parentRgt 
  FROM [nested-set] WHERE [id] = 3
) AS parent2 ON 1=1
JOIN [nested-set] AS child ON child.[lft] BETWEEN parent.[lft] AND parent.[rgt] 
WHERE parent.[lft] >= parentLft AND parent.[rgt] < parentRgt AND parent.[id] > 1 
GROUP BY child.[id] 
HAVING COUNT(child.[id]) = 1 
ORDER BY child.[lft] ASC
```

that gets children of a node in nested set model that runs perfectly fine on MySQL and SQLite (of course with different column quoting) but in order to get it to work on MS SQL Server I have to add all the columns in the GROUP BY clause. Since this query is supposed to run on different tables that only have id, lft and rgt columns in common having to specify all columns each time would be an overkill. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a subquery that returns the Id's you need, and then link the main table to that.

That way you don't need to specify the columns in the outer query.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM(
    SELECT child.id
    FROM [nested-set] headparent
    JOIN [nested-set] parent ON (parent.lft >= headparent.lft AND parent.rgt < headparent.rgt)
    JOIN [nested-set] child ON (child.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
    WHERE headparent.id = 3 
      AND parent.id > 1
    GROUP BY child.id
    HAVING count(*) = 1
) q
JOIN [nested-set] t ON t.id = q.id
ORDER BY t.lft ASC;
```

And since this is pretty much "Old Standard SQL" (f.e. doesn't use window functions), this should work also on MySql or SQLite.

**Post scriptum:**

I was wondering if it would be possible to use EXISTS for this.
And from the experiment below, it does seem so.  If you don't use a GROUP BY.
But i.m.h.o., the first method is a more straight forward way to pull it off.

```
declare @NestedSet table (id int, lft int, rgt int, colA int);

insert into @NestedSet (id,lft,rgt,colA) values
(1,3,5,100),
(2,4,5,200),
(3,3,6,300),
(4,3,5,400),
(5,4,6,500);

select *
from @NestedSet t
where exists (
    select 1
    from @NestedSet headparent
    join @NestedSet parent on (parent.lft >= headparent.lft and parent.rgt < headparent.rgt and parent.id > 1)
    where headparent.id = 3
    and t.lft between parent.lft and parent.rgt
    having count(*) = 1
);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: First to thank you for even giving this another thought.
Is there any advantage in one approach over the other?

Comment: The EXISTS method sometimes has it merits. F.e. when you just want fields from 1 table without needing any fields from the joined tables.  It can be faster in such case, because it stops looking for other matches as soon it finds at least 1 exists.  But this was just me fooling around with SQL. Wanted to see if it's possible to use a group by or having within an EXISTS. Turns out you can't GROUP on a field from the outer select inside the EXISTS clause. And it's harder to understand and test than with the subquery method.  Not even sure it's faster. So in this case I wouldn't recommend it.